# Firebase - should I recreate 'users'?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but the Firebase docs go round in circles.

I'm building an Android app and I'm authenticating users using `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` documented here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

That's straightforward and I can set the username, email etc. and its all stored somewhere (I've no idea where as its not displayed in the Firebase console) BUT I'm confused about user based authentication - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security in the examples here (and elsewhere on the net) we see the rules starting with `users`

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can see in the Firebase console there is no `users` child node in the database generated automatically from `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. So my question is should I create this or was a `users` child automatically created I just can't see it?

Its not a lot of work to implement an additional `user` child node and store user information there but it seems like a lot of duplication given that the authentication procedure has already stored the user information somewhere. The opposite way to ask this question is can I add the db write rules above and expect them to work if I have authenticated users but never added a `users` node in the db myself?

Why the docs don't spell this out is beyond me

Comment: You can view authenticated user on the Authentication screen in the console. Authenticated users aren't stored in the database and they only include user ID, email, and linked accounts. You can create a users node in your database to store additional details but it's a loose association.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why they do this? It seems like a big waste and duplication. I want one source of truth for a user so why not allow me to extend the authenticated users in the db?